# Use of Volatile variables for safe publication of Immutable objects

Tags: java, multithreading

I came across this statement:

> In properly constructed objects, all
>   threads will see correct values of
>   final fields, regardless of how the
>   object is published.

Then why a volatile variable is used to safely
publishing an Immutable object?

I'm really confused. Can anybody make it clear with a suitable example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case, the volatility would only ensure visibility of the new object; any other threads that happened to get hold of your object via a non-volatile field would indeed see the correct values of final fields as per [JSR-133's initialization safety guarantees](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp03304/#4.0).

Still, making the variable volatile doesn't hurt; is correct from a memory management perspective anyway; and *would* be necessary for non-final fields initialised in a constructor (although there shouldn't be any of these in an immutable object).  If you wish to share variables between threads, you'll need to ensure adequate synchronization to give *visibility* anyway; though in this case you're right, that there's no danger to the *atomicity* of the constructor.

Thanks to Tom Hawtin for pointing out I'd completely overlooked the JMM guarantees on final fields; previous incorrect answer is given below.

---

<s>The reason for the volatile variable is that is establishes a *[happens-before](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/memory.html#17.4.5)* relationship (according to the Java Memory Model) between the construction of the object, and the assignment of the variable.  This achieves two things:</s>

1. Subsequent reads of that variable from different threads are guaranteed to see the new value.  Without marking the variable as volatile, these threads could see stale values of the reference.
2. The *happens-before* relationship places limits on what reorderings the compiler can do.  Without a volatile variable, **the assignment to the variable could happen before the object's constructor runs** - hence other threads could get a reference to the object before it was fully constructed.

Since one of the fundamental rules of immutable objects is that you don't publish references during the constructor, it's this second point that is likely being referenced here.  In a multithreaded environment without proper concurrent handling, it *is* possible for a reference to the object to be "published" before that object has been constructed.  Thus another thread could get that object, see that one of its fields is `null`, and then later see that this "immutable" object has changed.

Note that you don't have to use volatile fields to achieve this if you have other appropriate synchronization primitives - for example, if the assignment (and all later reads) are done in a `synchronized` block on a given monitor - but in a "standalone" sense, marking the variable as `volatile` is the easiest way to tell the JVM "this might be read by multiple threads, please make the assignment safe in that context."

Comment: The JVM spec final-field semantics means that it is safe to unsafely published (appropriately designed) immutable objects. You might have further reasons to assign a reference to a volatile field, but you wont see uninitialised final fields without it.

Comment: @Tom - good point, which completely invalidates my answer.  I'll update appropriately.

Comment: how does this thread safe? since final fields are mutable..other threads might see different values right

Answer (score 2):

A volatile reference to an immutable object could be useful. This would allow you to swap one object for another to make the new data available to other threads.

I would suggets you look at using AtomicReference first however.

If you need final volatile fields you have a problem. All fields, including final ones are available to other threads as soon as the constructor returns. So if you pass an object to another thread in the constructor, it is possible for the other thread to see an inconsistent state. IMHO you should consider a different solution so you don't have to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You cant really see the difference in Immutable class.see the below example.in `Myclass.class`

```
    public static Foo getInstance(){
    if(INSTANCE == null){
        INSTANCE = new Foo();
    }

    return INSTANCE;
}
```

in the above code if Foo is declared **final**(`final Foo INSTANCE;`) it guarantees that it won't publish references during the constructor call.partial object construction is not possible

consider this...if this `Myclass` is Immutable, its state is not gonna change after object construction, making Volatile(`volatile final Foo INSTANCE;`) keyword redundant.but if this class allows its object state to be changed(Not immutable) multiple threads CAN actually update the object and some updates are not visible to other threads, *hence volatile keyword  ensures safety publication of objects in non-Immutable class*.